# zoomLevel and mapCenter in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

I'm creating a Map app in iPhone using `MKMapView`.

I did successfully find my `current location` and `zoom` on that point like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}

-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1550, 1550);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

The problem that I want to solve is:

I have a `location` on the `map` (this code in `viewDidLoad`):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self getLocationFromAddressString:@"San Francisco, CA, United States"];
//    location.latitude = 37.78608;
//    location.longitude = -122.407398;

    MapViewAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Store location" coordinate:location];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
```

and this is the `mapViewAnnotation:`

```
@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;

- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) t coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _title = t;
        _coordinate = c;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I want to have a proper `zoomLevel` and `mapCenter` for this `location` and my `current location`.

I could do that successfully in Android using `MapController.zoomToSpan()`. How can I fix it in iPhone Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way that I could implement it:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

    for(id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations) {
        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
    region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;

    // Add a little extra space on the sides
    region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

    region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

create array of location and after that center mapview with all AnnotationPins

```
-(void) RoutscenterMap 
{
        MKCoordinateRegion region;

        CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90;
        CLLocationDegrees maxLon = -180;
        CLLocationDegrees minLat = 90;
        CLLocationDegrees minLon = 180;
        for(int idx = 0; idx < arrLocation.count; idx++)// here use your array or points
        {
            CLLocation* currentLocation = [arrLocation objectAtIndex:idx];
            if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude > maxLat)
                maxLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude < minLat)
                minLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude > maxLon)
                maxLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
            if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude < minLon)
                minLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        }

        region.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
        region.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
        region.span.latitudeDelta  = (maxLat - minLat) * 2;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxLon - minLon) * 2;

        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
```

also you can add location in array like bellow...

```
 CLLocation *temploc=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longtitude];
 [arrLocation addObject:temploc];
```

after that use this array to center the map

i hope this help you...

:)

Comment: It is somehow hardcoded. have you worked with `MapController.zoomToSpan()` in Android? the thing is I want to center,zoom between my current location and the `CLLocationCoordinate2D location`, your code is not helping me for that.

Comment: what about `didAddAnnotationViews` method that I have? where should I use your method?

Comment: hey mate its very easy just see if you create array with CLLocationCoordinate2D object which store you two location and add this in arrLocation and call this method in LocationUpdate method or viewWillAppear method.. just try to use it..

Comment: also call in didAddAnnotationViews method

Comment: but `didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views`as you see has an NSArray. I could use it for my current location. (you can see in the code that I shared in the question), but how about my `CLLocationCoordinate2D location`? do I have to create my own ´arrLocation´? then what is the usage of _NSArray Parameter?

Comment: I just try to use your code. I got an exception: `2012-10-04 MapKitDemo[1802:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+0.00000000, +0.00000000 span:-360.00000000, -720.00000000>'
***`

Comment: After calling startUpdatingLocation, it may take a few seconds for the location to be updated so you can't try to retrieve it immediately afterwards. Until it is updated, location contains invalid values which is what the error tells you.

Instead, implement the locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: delegate method and read the location in there.

Move all the code after startUpdatingLocation to that method

Comment: try for center the map, create Method and in that method write [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; and after call above method bt check that our custom arrLocation is not empty ok mate.. :)

Comment: I couldn't implement your approach, but by the way I found a solution.   +1 for you help.